Py_Initialize return No module named 'encoding'
I tried to use CPython in my c++ project, but after running Py_Initialize i got error like below. I'm using python venv, and the initialization code is simple as
class PyRuntime {
public:
    PyRuntime() {
        Py_Initialize();
        if (PyErr_Occurred())
            throw(std::runtime_error("Py_Initialize failed"));
    }

    ~PyRuntime() {
        Py_Finalize();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    PyRuntime rt;
    return 0;
}


Error message is like below
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'


This question is similar to: How to embed Python 3.12 in a Windows C++ app?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@AhmedAEK my question is on Linux platform(to be more specific, Debian), and the link you provided is a Windows one.

my question is on Linux platform, this should be part of the question, not a comment.

As pointed on the linked question, python cannot find its standard libraries.
On linux the process is different, you need to add to python paths the folder that contains the standard library instead of setting python home, this depends on the python version, but the base installation should use /usr/lib/python3.12/, if you are using a venv then it should have a similar folder that contains the standard library inside your venv, you may also need to add /usr/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload/ if your venv doesn't contain the needed shared objects.
If python is installed in a different location then you can find those paths by inspecting sys.path when running python.
#include "Python.h"
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

class PyRuntime {
public:
    
    PyRuntime(char* exe_path) {
        PyStatus status;

        PyConfig config;
        PyConfig_InitPythonConfig(&config);

        status = PyConfig_SetBytesString(&config, &config.program_name,
                                    exe_path);
        if (PyStatus_Exception(status)) {
            throw(std::runtime_error("PyConfig_SetBytesString failed"));
        }

        config.module_search_paths_set = 1;
        status = PyWideStringList_Append(&config.module_search_paths,
                                        L"/usr/lib/python3.12/");
        if (PyStatus_Exception(status)) {
            throw(std::runtime_error("PyWideStringList_Append failed"));
        }
        
        status = Py_InitializeFromConfig(&config);
        if (PyStatus_Exception(status)) {
            throw(std::runtime_error("Py_Initialize failed"));
        }
    }

    ~PyRuntime() {
        Py_Finalize();
    }
};


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    PyRuntime rt{argv[0]};
    PyRun_SimpleString("print(\"hello world\")");
    return 0;
}

